# How to get only first object when 2 objects match if statement

Tags: javascript

```js
const cars = [{
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '1997'
}, {
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '2011'
}]
Object.keys(cars).forEach(function(x) {
 if (cars[x].brand == "BMW") {
  console.log(cars[x]);
 }
});
```

How do I console.log only first object of the array matches brand "BMW"?
*It has to be a solution with object keys

Comment: `cars` is an array. Why would you use `Object.keys()`? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and if a brand is found return `true` - then the iteration stops.

```js
const cars = [{ brand: 'BMW', year: '1997' }, { brand: 'BMW', year: '2011' }];

Object.keys(cars).some(function(x) {
    if (cars[x].brand == "BMW") {
        console.log(cars[x]);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, well so simple heh. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

user **`array.find`**, It will return only the first matching element.

```js
const cars = [{
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '1997'
}, {
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '2011'
}]

console.log(cars.find(car=>car.brand ==='BMW'));
```

**EDIT**

Since you need a solution with Object.Keys, you can use array.some()

```js
const cars = [{
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '1997'
}, {
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '2011'
}]

Object.keys(cars).some(function(ele) {
 if (cars[ele].brand == "BMW") {
        console.log(cars[ele]);
        return true;
 }
});
```

Comment: OP said "It has to be a solution with object.keys()"

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes updated but i am not sure why OP needs that :)

Comment: yes with the above code he just needs to add a check

Answer (score 0):

The above answer of using `Array.prototype.find()` is definitely what you are looking for.

However, if you run into this issue under other circumstances: When you are using a for loop, and you want to end the loop early, you can use the "break" keyword.

The break keyword does not work with `forEach`, however you should not be using forEach anyway -- it has less browser support and is slower than an old-fashioned for loop.

Comment: `Array.prototype.find()` is the solution but you advise to not use `.forEach()` because of its browser support? O.o `.forEach()` is available in every browser and `.find()` not

Comment: I actually wasn't aware find wasn't well supported, as I don't really use it. I would have really advised to just use a for loop and break, and only accepted find because another user already mentioned it and it is the exact method for the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful to you

```js
var Exception = {};
const cars = [{
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '1997'
}, {
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '2011'
}]
try{
Object.keys(cars).forEach(function(x) {
 if (cars[x].brand == "BMW") {
  console.log(cars[x]);
        throw Exception;
 }
});
}catch(e){
   if (e !== Exception) throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.keys(cars).find(function)` like below :

```js
const cars = [{
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '1997'
}, {
 brand: 'BMW',
 year: '2011'
}]

Object.keys(cars).find(function(x) {
if (cars[x].brand == "BMW") {
    console.log(cars[x]);
    return true;
   }
});
```